# Regex: match if vowels occur in a word in order (aeiou), and not match if there is a char other than a char

Tags: regex

I am trying to match if a word has `aeiou` and it has to be in order of `aeiou`. It also is not supposed to match if there is a char that is not a word. For example:

Match:

```
cabeilous
```

Not Match:

```
sacrilegious 
jeious 
cabeil-ous
```

This is what I have so far:

```
.a[^e]*e[^i]*i[^o]*o[^u]*u.
```

this is matching on `sacrilegious`.

Comment: How are repetitions handled? Should `aaeiou` match? How about `aeeiou` and `aeiouu`?

Comment: Also what about `oaiuoekaeioukieoua` (*there's aeiou in the good order between the k's, even if it isn't the case after and before*). In other words: is a word acceptable if your conditions are only satisfied in a part of the word?

Comment: If you just want to check for unique occurence of `aeiou` in order, I'd strip out any consonants and check if this sequence is left. In PHP eg [`preg_replace('/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+/i', "", strtolower($str))=="aeiou")`](https://eval.in/1107495)

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude all the other vowels in each negation if that's what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[^\Waeiou]*a[^\Waeiou]*e[^\Waeiou]*i[^\Waeiou]*o[^\Waeiou]*u[^\Waeiou]*$/
```

should do the trick. Anchor both sides of the string and exclude any non-word characters and anything out of place. You can allow repetitions such as `aeeiou` by excluding each vowel from the character class immediately following it.

```js
const pattern = /^[^\Waeiou]*a[^\Waeiou]*e[^\Waeiou]*i[^\Waeiou]*o[^\Waeiou]*u[^\Waeiou]*$/;

[
  "cabeilous",    // yep
  "sacrilegious", // nope
  "jeious",       // nope
  "cabeil-ous",   // nope
  "aaeiou",       // nope
  "aeeiou",       // nope
  "aeiiou",       // nope
  "aeioou",       // nope
  "aeiouu",       // nope
].forEach(test => console.log(test, pattern.test(test)));

const patternWithReps = /^[^\Waeiou]*a[^\Weiou]*e[^\Waiou]?i[^\Waeou]*?o[^\Waeiu]*?u[^\Waeio]*$/;

console.log("\n~~ with repetition: ~~");

[
  "cabeilous",    // yep
  "sacrilegious", // nope
  "jeious",       // nope
  "cabeil-ous",   // nope
  "aaeiou",       // yep
  "aeeiou",       // yep
  "aeiiou",       // yep
  "aeioou",       // yep
  "aeiouu",       // yep
].forEach(test => console.log(test, patternWithReps.test(test)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might help you to pass your desired output, and fail others:

```
^([a-z]+)?(?:[a-z]*a(?:[a-z]*e(?:[a-z]*i(?:[a-z]*o(?:[a-z]*u)))))([a-z]+)?$
```

Here, we can use a layer by layer architecture to check every letter in order, then we can add a list of chars for those we wish to have behind it. I've just assumed that `[a-z]` might be a desired list of char.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lGd3mw/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo for Capturing Groups

```js
const regex = /^([a-z]+)?(?:[a-z]*a(?:[a-z]*e(?:[a-z]*i(?:[a-z]*o(?:[a-z]*u)))))([a-z]+)?$/gm;
const str = `aeiou
cabeilous
zaaefaifoafua
sacrilegious 
jeious 
cabeil-ous`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your pattern works (for what you want to do, since the question is still unclear), but what the point of all of these nested non-capturing groups? Note that if you remove them all, you obtain exactly the same result with less steps. Also why writing `([a-z]+)?` instead of `([a-z]*)`?